# R efficient Drilldown chart with loop using Highchart

Tags: r, highcharts, coding-efficiency, drilldown

I bring you a problem in which I have found myself when doing a job.
I need to perform a 'drilldown' that contains around 100 columns and I am running into an efficiency issue.
The data set contains the years from 1913 to 2021.

```
# Load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(highcharter)
```

```
# Example Data Frame
df <- data.frame(year = c('1913-01-01',
                          '1913-01-02',
                          '1913-01-03',
                          '1913-01-04',
                          '1913-01-05',
                          '1913-01-06',
                          '1913-01-07',
                          '1913-01-08',
                          '1913-01-09',
                          '1913-01-10',
                          '1913-01-11',
                          '1913-01-12',
                          '1914-01-01',
                          '1914-01-02',
                          '1914-01-03',
                          '1914-01-04',
                          '1914-01-05',
                          '1914-01-06',
                          '1914-01-07',
                          '1914-01-08',
                          '1914-01-09',
                          '1914-01-10',
                          '1914-01-11',
                          '1914-01-12'),
                 value = 1:12)
```

I need to create a drilldown where the average of the values in each year are shown, in this example they would be only 2 but in the original data frame there would be around 100 columns that should be shown in the graph

The way I can think of is the following:

```
df1913 <- df %>%
  filter(year(year) == 1913) %>%
  data.frame()

df1914 <- df %>%
  filter(year(year) == 1914) %>%
  data.frame()
```

```
dfDD <- tibble(name = year(df$year),
               y = mean(df$value),
               drilldown = substr(name, 1, 4))
```

I would have to repeat this code for each data frame I would need to create and I recognize that it is not efficient.

Example:

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
  hc_title(text = "Example Drilldown") %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
  hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(series = list(boderWidth = 2,
                               dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE))) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = dfDD,
                name = "Mean",
                colorByPoint = TRUE) %>%
  hc_drilldown(allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
               series = list(list(id = "1913",
                                  data = list_parse2(df1913)),
                             list(id = '1914',
                                  data = list_parse2(df1914))))
```

**UPDATE: May 07, 2022**

**EDIT:**

It was necessary for me to reformulate my question since I have expressed myself in an incorrect way and that is why I did not get the answer to my main problem.
First of all I thank everyone who has read and commented on his opinion about my problem.

Reformulated question:

I need to create a 'drilldown' style chart. My original dataset has only 2 columns:

- date
- value

For each year I have 12 values ​​(1 for each month of the year).
The problem is that the data set has the years from 1913 to 2021 registered in the 'years' column. It would be around 1300 rows. If I don't count wrong, it's 109 years where each year has 12 values ​​and only the year 2021 has 7.

In the way that I had explained before, my way of solving the problem was inefficient and very long. Having to create a data frame for each subset of the year would be tedious and I would have more than 100 data frames created.

Is there a more efficient way to solve my problem!?
If so, could you explain it to me with an example?
Thank you very much and sorry for expressing myself poorly at first.

[Data Source](https://drive.google.com/file/d/196ZSi9EB1o1jBWxpfqNghjO7HcAorM9v/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your example dataframe **df**, process the data slightly to add variable *year* as character:

```
df <- df %>% 
    mutate(YMD = ymd(year),
           year = as.character(year(YMD)))
```

... and do the grouping and aggregation during the composition of your plot (no need to cram your workspace with dataframelets):

```
library(dplyr)

## (preceding plot instructions omitted)
## ...
hc_add_series(data = df %>%
                  group_by(year) %>%
                  summarise(y = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
                  mutate(name = year, drilldown = year) #, ... other args
              ) %>%
hc_drilldown(allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
             series = list(
                 df %>%
                 group_by(year) %>%
                 summarise(drilldown_series = 
                               list(id = first(year),
                                    data =  list_parse2(
                                        df = .[c('year', 'value')] )
                                    )
                           ) %>%
                 pull(drilldown_series)
             )
```

If your dataframe has a lot of columns, you might want to stack these, e.g with `pivot_longer`, i. e. you narrow these columns down to two: one contains the variable name, the second its value:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = first_column_to_stack : last_col_to_stack,
                 names_to = "variable",
                 values_to = "value"
                 )
```

... now you can dynamically `filter` the long-format dataframe by variable (and year and ...) before feeding it as plot arguments.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question.
I had to rewrite my question as I had not expressed myself correctly and it has led to misinterpretations. If you have time, could you read it again? Thank you very much and sorry for wasting your time at first

Comment: No problem. The key is (I think) to find a rapid chain of list-handling functions (e. g. from package purrr: https://purrr.tidyverse.org/) to produce the deeply nested list required for `hc_drilldown`). Which is lamentably not one of my strengths ;-) Maybe you can issue a  separate question on just how to get the required *nested list* from a *grouped dataframe* providing minimum example data of (A) dataframe as is and (B) list as should be - so that the list specialists can take over for solutions how to get from A to B.